# submitting values through a form with select Box (php)

Tags: php, xhtml

Okay I've spent the last hour trying to find a solution to this but no luck, so I'll ask you guys to see if you can help!

As simple as this seems how can I submit the value of a select box to an external php page!

I'm sure this code should work, but it isn't submitting the value at all.

```
test.php
    <form action="test2.php"
         method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
    What is your Gender?

    <select name="formGender">
      <option value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="M">Male</option>
      <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" 
            name="submit"
            value="Submit" />
            </form>




test2.php

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) )
    {

      $varGender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formGender']);

      echo $varGender;
      }
      else{
      echo "Something went wrong";
      }
    ?>
```

Yet I always end up getting the "Something went wrong" meaning the data isn't submitting. Any help anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST['formSubmit']` is never going to be set because you don't have a field with a name of 'formSubmit'. How about `if(isset($_POST['formGender']))`?

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot that! Sorry about this guys